# explicit get route is throwing an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing, named-routing

I defined a custom route:

`match 'folio/:id' => 'posts#show', :as => :folio, :via => :get`

When I run `rake routes` command I have:

```
post  GET    /posts/:id(.:format)     posts#show
folio GET    /folio/:id(.:format)     posts#show
```

And I put link for this element in my other page: `link_to post.title, folio_path` ,but when I enter it throws me an routing error:

`No route matches {:controller=>"post", :action=>"show"}`

Why it fails? When I'm using `post#show` in normal way it works like a charm, but with my custom route it fails - please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the post so rails can fill the `id` part:

```
link_to post.title, folio_path(post)
```